# Some frameworks for Xamarin Forms about UI controls?

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin.forms, frameworks

Does anyone know any open-source framework for Xamarin Forms that looks like MahApps Metro for WPF? (a framework that has more beautiful controls than the default ones)

Comment: I have the same question. It seems that there are no free UI libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Syncfusion ui controls for Xamarin.Forms https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls. Also there are community license you can use free.